# Listener mouse entered and key pressed at the same time

Tags: java, swing, events, listener

I have JFrame which contains JPanel. How to write listener to check when key(let it be SHIFT) is pressed and mouse enters to the JPanel area at the same time?

Comment: Why?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: I know how to implement mouse entering/exiting component, I know how to implement key pressing, but how to make it work at the same time?

Comment: *"how to make it work at the same time?"*  That much was already clear, but ***why*** do you want to detect both at the same time?  It seems a shortcut to an unusable GUI to me.  Explain how it actually makes sense to do what you are attempting.

Comment: Suppose I have table of JPanel's 10x10 on frame. I want to change their background colors when I press the SHIFT and move my mouse from one panel to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MouseEvent` provides information about the state of various elements, including some keys, via it's modifier properties, for example...

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    int modifiersEx = e.getModifiersEx();
    int onmask = MouseEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK;
    if ((modifiersEx & onmask) == onmask) {
        // Shift key is down
    }
}
```

Will allow you to detect when the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed when the mouse enters a given component.

Take a look at...

- [`MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html)
- [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

...for more details